# Pycharm cannot resolve some Python Standard Libraries like time and sys

Tags: python, pycharm

I just downloaded Pycharm Community Edition 3.4 today and this problem annoys me.

Pycharm doesn't detect stdlibs that doesn't have a `__file__` attributes, thus incorrectly marking those as errors, like in the snapshot below.

[image: Annoying highlights of unresolved modules]

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Thanks for the suggestion. I just did. [Link here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13176#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue using Pycharm Professional 3.4 running on Arch Linux.

To fix the problem I removed the Python Interpreter configuration for python 2.7 and readded as described in comments section of the bug report.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13176#